# ffmpeg - Center image without stretching

Tags: image, ffmpeg, stretch

I'm trying with ffmpeg to insert an image with vertical orientation in a video with 1280x720 resolution. Actually ffmpeg stretch the image but i want that center image (so with height 720) and doesn't stretch width. Any solution?

> ffmpeg -r 1/5 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -i 1.mp2 -af
>   "afade=t=out:st=15:d=5" -vf "format=yuv420p" -shortest -s 1280x720
>   -aspect 16:9 -codec:v libx264 out.mp4